# how to view uploaded django imagefield image from browser?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models

I am using a django image field.  I am uploading images to my servers apache server in a folder named images.  When I try to access the image via  browser with the url format:

http://mydomain.com/images/myimage.png

I get a 404 error because django is intercepting my request.

How do I access from a browser a django uploaded image from an image field?

Thanks!

Comment: You have defined the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings file right? Then you should do something like this `http://mydomain.com/media/images/myimage.png` if that does not work try to print this `obj.image.url` to get the url of uploaded image, if the image field is named as `image`.

Comment: try `http://mydomain.com/static/images/myimage.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up directives for your media that will allow apache to directly serve static/media files instead of passing the request to django. Here's an example VirtualHost configuration that you can use.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@{{ maildomain }}
    ServerName {{ fqdn }}

    WSGIDaemonProcess {{ projectname }} python-path=/var/www/{{ projectname }}/environ/lib/python{{ pyversion }}/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup {{ projectname }}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/{{ projectname }}/project/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/{{ projectname }}/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/{{ projectname }}/files/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/{{ projectname }}/static/
    Alias /files /var/www/{{ projectname }}/files/


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/{{ projectname }}/logs/errors.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/{{ projectname }}/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am also setting the MEDIA_ROOT in settings to the static directory, as well as having the upload_to parameter of the imagefield to a folder in the static directory.  This now works.